# UIWebView not showing website

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have created some simple code designed to show a webpage, which has been working perfectly fine since I created it. However, when I now run the app, the UIWebView no longer displays the webpage, although the NSLog shows the code is definitely being run.

In the .h: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;`

In the .m:

```
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com";
[self createWebpage:url];

self.addressBar.delegate = self;

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) createWebpage:(NSString *)webString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webString];
    NSURLRequest *requestUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestUrl];
    NSLog(@"Webpage is created!");
}
```

I recently (accidentally) deleted a Referencing Outlet between the back and forward UIButtons I had created. I say this in case it has anything to do with the problem. All help appreciated.

EDIT: I don't know why, but the app now does not load. It goes to the splash screen, and then errors, producing the error log below.

```
2014-09-21 14:19:14.273 Fullscreen Ninja Browser for iPhone 6[6673:349224] Webpage is created!
2014-09-21 14:19:14.278 Fullscreen Ninja Browser for iPhone 6[6673:349224] *** Assertion failure in -[NSLayoutConstraint constant], /SourceCache/Foundation_Sim/Foundation-1140.11/Layout.subproj/NSLayoutConstraint.m:643
2014-09-21 14:19:14.283 Fullscreen Ninja Browser for iPhone 6[6673:349224] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '(null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a073f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001056a0bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a0725a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001052be28f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010523a18d -[NSLayoutConstraint constant] + 170
    5   Foundation                          0x0000000105243ea3 -[NSLayoutConstraint _lowerIntoExpression:reportingConstantIsRounded:] + 197
    6   Foundation                          0x0000000105239dbe -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 96
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000106474495 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 474
    8   Foundation                          0x0000000105247a8e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010647429b __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 452
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001064740ae -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 197
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106473d21 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 404
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000106468caf -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_windowDidChange] + 127
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000105e66d85 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 207
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000105e5f9c2 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 125
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000105e5f936 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 437
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000105e69835 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1550
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000105e37f43 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 452
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000105e38152 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 276
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000105e4465c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000105def191 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000105df1e5c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000105df0d22 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001085a92a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010593cabc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105932805 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001059325c5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105931a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000105df0799 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000105df3550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    30  Fullscreen Ninja Browser for iPhone 6 0x00000001051723c3 main + 115
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107f7f145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Edit 2: I have discovered that when I "Add missing constraints" to my UIButton, the above error is caused. However, when I clear the constraints, the app runs fine, with the UIWebView showing the site. However, the buttons are out of place, as adding constraints causes the app to crash, annoyingly. Any solutions?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't delete the outlet for the web view as well?

Comment: When I click on the UIWebView in the Interface Builder, it says there's a Referencing Outlet between the webView and the View Controller.

Comment: You know what, you should call [super viewDidLoad] before you use any view or do anything with your ui. That seems to be your problem.

Comment: I edited my question. The app is now not loading, so I can't tell if the change is showing the webpage or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `[super viewDidLoad]`, before loading your webView,
This should help to resolve your issue,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com";
    [self createWebpage:url];
    self.addressBar.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: The app is now not loading at all :\ Regardless of where I put the super. See my edit please :)

Comment: Try to delete the application, restart simulator and Xcode, open the project again, hit "cmd + K" in xcode, and run again, hope this will help.

Comment: that's strange, can you commit your project to github? so I can run and understand the problem

Comment: I've discovered the problem by creating a new project and gradually copying everything in. When I "Add missing constraints" to my UIButtons, the app errors. However, when I Clear these constraints, the app runs fine, apart from my buttons being out of place...

Comment: Seems, that's a autoLayout problem, try to disable AutoLayout if you don't need it http://i.imgur.com/1zLg6DM.png

Comment: I disabled it, but it then doesn't put the Buttons and UITextField in the correct positions :\ Thanks for your help anyway :)